# Android app to open password-protected files within a ZIP

Tags: android, zip

I often get emailed ZIP files containing one or more password-protected files, but the standard Android tools don't even try to open them. Is there a ZIP viewer that can handle them? I have the password, of course.

Comment: I mean whatever launches when I click on a ZIP attachment in GMail - I see now it is Cx File Explorer that is providing the functionality - I'll delete that bit from my question.

Comment: If I remember correctly I had once open a password protected ZIP files using [WinRAR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar) app.

Comment: I'll try that; I've also fired off an email to the makers of Cx File Explorer to see if they plan to add the feature.